# Processing IDE launch - None of the Processing 2.0 versions (beta versions & the stable versions) launch

Tags: java, ide, launch, processing-ide

I've been working on processing for prototyping for the past 3 months and I have used processing2.0b9, processing2.0b8, and processing1.5.1 on my Windows 7 PC. It was loading and working perfectly fine until 2 days ago. Suddenly, all the processing 2.0 versions don't load at all. The loading image having "Processing initiated by Ben Fry & Casey Reas" loads and then nothing happens. So, here are the things that I tried in the last 48 hours:
(a) Reinstalled the application - 6 times
(b) Reinstalled my Java JRE - 3 times
(c) Tried removing the preferences.txt file.
(d) Tried debugging through the command prompt.
(e) Tried running it in a different destination folder & drive.

Nothing works. Usually, my Windows Task Manager's processes tab shows a "javaw.exe" as soon as a Processing application runs. Now nothing shows up there as well. The weirdest part is that Processing 1.5.1 still opens & runs. My sketches are safe & so are my libraries. But they are rather dormant. The PDE files don't show the Processing icon that it once showed.

I've already lost 2 days in trying to load the IDE/App for Processing 2.0b8, processing2.0b9, & processing 2.0.1. Any help is appreciated.

PS>> Source suspicion: I once loaded the G4P's createGUI() in the draw() function just to experiment. And when I hit the run, it put out a fatal error because I stopped it abruptly through the task manager as the draw() function called the createGUI() function in an infinite loop. I suspect if that termination caused such a problem.

Update: The application seems to be running on the background because after tryring to run the application's IDE, (clicking processing.exe), and finding that the IDE isn't launching, when I tried moving the Processing folder, it says that a File is open in the Folder.

Comment: Try removing any installed tools you have...

Comment: I would only try with 2.0.1, had problems with 2.0b8 and 9

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: https://forum.processing.org/topic/processing-ide-launch-none-of-the-processing-2-0-versions-beta-versions-the-stable-versions

Sorry about sharing the link. But didn't want to repeat the response here. Looks like the Processing team is now looking into the issue themselves. (Casey Reas himself has replied about the issue in the thread.)

Thanks a lot for your replies.